# How to concatenate multiple images in 2d directions using Imagemagick?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have a bunch of images of the same size. I want to stack them onto and beside each other in 2d space.
(tl: top-left)

```
tl | tr  
bl | br
```

I'm currently first stacking horizontally, then stacking vertically like this:

```
convert +append tl.png tr.png top.png
convert +append bl.png br.png bottom.png
convert -append top.png bottom.png out.png
```

I'd like to do this for any number of images (not just 4) and any 2d geometry. I think there is a better way to do this thing. Something along the lines of `convert stack (0,0)tl (0,1)tr (1,0)bl (1,1)br` so we can specify the exact location of placement of each segment...

Comment: You might be looking for the [montage](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) command?

Comment: There is insufficient information in your question to answer it. How are your images named if there are 8, or 9 or 16?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Set the origin of a Cartesian system at top left. y-axis points downwards, x-axis rightwards.
I want image_i be at (x,y).

Comment: You do that with `montage`. If you want 3 images across the page and 2 images down `montage IMAGELIST -tile 3x2 RESULT.PNG`. If you want 4 images across the page and however many rows are needed `-tile 4x`. If you want 5 images down the page and however many columns are needed `tile x5`